# How to save a PDF document item in outlook to a file location using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, outlook, office-automation

In a inbox folder in outlook I have a pdf file, not as attachment but as a documentitem (class 41) placed by hand. With a VBA application in Excel I want to copy the PDF-file to a file location on my c-drive so i can import it in Excel to extract some information. Using the SaveAs method i can't save the file as PDF. Is there a other solution to copy the PDF from the outlook folder to a file location using vba?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any other method or property for that. The [DocumentItem.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.documentitem.saveas) method saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type.